# PHP redirect based on IP addresses

Tags: php, redirect

I need to show content for specific range of IP addresses and the others I want to redirect.

I have found this code for checking IP address:

```
<?php 

$ip_ban = array();
$ip_ban[] = "10.10.*.*"; 
$ip_ban[] = "10.111.111.10";

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$ip_ban)) 
{
    header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com/"); 
} 
else
{
    //Do loop through bans:
    foreach($ip_ban as $ban) 
    {
        if(eregi($ban,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) 
        {
            header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com/"); 
        }

        //Finished loop
    }

} ?>
```

The code works, it really redirects to yahoo, but I need to show content instead of redirection. And redirect all other IP addresses.

How can I modify the script?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is strange. Those `in_array` matches against the wildcard ips is for nothing. just think of all IPs are preg patterns.

```
<?php 

$ip_ban = [
  "10\.10\.\d\.\d"; 
  "10\.111\.111\.10"
];

foreach($ip_ban as $ban) 
{
    if(\preg_match("/$ban/", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) 
    {
        header("Location: http://www.yahoo.com/");
        exit;
    }
}

echo "not banned";
```